# Textual reference of Section + Number reference of Subsection

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there any simple way to make

> "Textual reference of Section" followed by "Number reference of Subsection"

with one command?

What I want to see is e.g., `Appendix A.1`, in which "Appendix" is the name of the (higher-level) section and "A.1" is the number of (lower-level) subsection.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you look into the [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package and its main user command, `\cref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
A cross-reference to \cref{sec:appA1}.

\appendix
\section{Additional results}
\subsection{Proofs of various theorems} \label{sec:appA1}
\dots
\end{document}
```